# Java Spring Rest API 404 error

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, postman

I'm making a RestApi in Java Spring(Gradle). When compile th code, and try it in Postman it returns with 404. I dont know why, and it is very annoying.

```
package arma.Arma.RestController;

import arma.Arma.Service.UserService;
import arma.Arma.doman.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "api/user")
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<User> getAll() {
        return userService.getAll();
    }
}
```

UserService

```
package arma.Arma.Service;

import arma.Arma.Repository.UserRepository;
import arma.Arma.doman.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<User> getAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

User

```
package arma.Arma.doman;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "user_type", nullable = false)
    private UserType type;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I read tonns of solutions, and none of them helped. Also, it is the first time it appeared, I configured Tomcat, Java, MySql, etc in many machines, and now I'm really helpless.

Comment: Post the sent request :)

Comment: localhost:8080/api/user/all

Comment: @ViktorKenéz I imagine you've tried it in your browser also? Did you change anything in your configuration files?

Comment: What type of container do you use to start your application? Spring boot? Did you include spring-boot-starter-web?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Spring Boot, yes i included spring-boot-started-web

Comment: 404 response code means what your app can't find appropriate request executor. There are few different cases why it may occurs. You sure what your controller register in context? Show your app structure, please.

Comment: Are you getting any response body with status 404, paste it

Comment: https://ibb.co/bBtzic

Comment: https://ibb.co/d4Ui9H

Comment: Ok, let me see your ArmaApplication class?

Comment: Have a look at this code snippet, Its working. resued your classes and just removed your db layer code to return dummy response, https://ideone.com/rlNH2V

Comment: package arma.Arma;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ArmaApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(ArmaApplication.class, args);
 }
}

the application class

Comment: According to your log http://ibb.co/bBtzic the application was not started